# Adding line separator for answers in the close vote review

Tags: feature-request, review, design, vote-to-close

In the close vote review, for the duplicate questions, in the Duplicate tab, the answers are not separated with the line separator.

For an example in this [close vote review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/56090), the answers in the ***Duplicate*** tab are not separated with the line separator (border-bottom). Adding the separator will help the better readability.

> [image: No border-bottom]

Can the border bottom to be added in the answers section.